# Tags: [isotope] and [jquery-isotope]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tag [isotope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isotope) has currently 57 questions.

In my opinion, these questions would fit better in the existing tag [jquery-isotope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-isotope), which currently has 1.256 questions.

What should we do with [isotope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isotope)?

Comment: Let it's half-life run off?